# How to add a new row using a button in MS Word?

Tags: vba, windows, ms-word

How to add a new row using a button in MS Word?

The new row must copy the drop-down list, which should be the default for all new rows.

[image: 1]

As shown in the image, when I click on the 'Add Row' button it must add a new now on table number 3 including the drop-down list.

currently i have the code which add only new row without the drop-down list.

```vb
Private Sub AddRowCommandButton1_Click()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim row As row
    Dim cell As cell
    Dim combo As FormField
    Dim dropDown As ContentControl
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Set the table
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(3) ' Change the index if your table is not the first table in the document
    
    ' Check if a table exists in the document
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No table found in the document.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Check if the specified cell exists in the table
    If tbl.Columns.Count < 6 Or tbl.Rows.Count < 2 Then
        MsgBox "Table does not have enough rows and columns.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    tbl.Rows.Add
    
    Set row = tbl.Rows(3)   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That can be done without any code by using a Repeating Section Content Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Insert a row at the end of the table
- Copy the last cell from the above row

```vb
Sub AddRow()
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim lastRow As row
    Dim newRow As row
    Dim lastCell As cell
    Dim newCell As cell
    If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count > 2 Then
        MsgBox "No target table found in the document.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(3)
    Set lastRow = oTbl.Rows(oTbl.Rows.Count)
    Set lastCell = lastRow.Cells(lastRow.Cells.Count)
    lastCell.Select
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
    Set newRow = oTbl.Rows(oTbl.Rows.Count)
    Set newCell = newRow.Cells(newRow.Cells.Count)
    lastCell.Range.Copy
    newCell.Range.Paste
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.InsertRowsBelow method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertrowsbelow?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663193)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well. The one thing I need to do is to protect the second row from deletion, where the data is initially copied to the next row. If the user deletes all rows, then we need to manually add the first row.